# Method scrollToItemAtIndexPath is not working on iOS 14

Tags: ios, ios14, collectionview

I am having an issue with `scrollToItemAtIndexPath` from iOS 14.
In the previous iOS versions when the user stopped dragging, the next cell was centered horizontally, now the method  `scrollToItemAtIndexPath` is  ignored, and it remains stuck in the first cell.

```
    - (void)scrollViewWillEndDragging:(UIScrollView *)scrollView withVelocity:(CGPoint)velocity targetContentOffset:(inout CGPoint *)targetContentOffset {
    if( scrollView.tag == 1 ) {
        if (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() != UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad){
            *targetContentOffset = scrollView.contentOffset; // set acceleration to 0.0
            float pageWidth = (float) (self.view.frame.size.width)-80;
            int minSpace = 10;
            
            int cellToSwipe = (scrollView.contentOffset.x)/(pageWidth + minSpace) + (velocity.x < 0 ? 0 : 1); // cell width + min spacing for lines
            if (cellToSwipe < 0) {
                cellToSwipe = 0;
            } else if (cellToSwipe >= MIN(6, self.news.count )) {
                cellToSwipe = (int) MIN(6, self.news.count);
            }
            [self.newsCollectionView scrollToItemAtIndexPath: [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:cellToSwipe inSection:0]
                                            atScrollPosition: UICollectionViewScrollPositionCenteredHorizontally
                                                    animated: YES];

        }
    }
    
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `layoutAttributesForItem(at indexPath: IndexPath)` of the `UICollectionViewLayout` to calculate a proper contentOffset

The fix could be like that:

```
extension UICollectionView {
    func scrollTo(indexPath: IndexPath) {
        let attributes = collectionViewLayout.layoutAttributesForItem(at: indexPath)!
        setContentOffset(attributes.frame.origin, animated: true)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

`scrollToItemAtIndexPath` still has some problems on iOS 14, you can use `setContentOffset`instead, and it works for me.

Comment: how did you manage to do it with setContentOffset ?

Comment: because my offset is easy to calculate, so I use  `setContentOffset `

Comment: 1.get the size of the cell 2.get the target index 3.i can calculate the offset

Answer (score 2):

Objective-C version:

```
UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes *attributes = [collectionView layoutAttributesForItemAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForItem:index inSection:section]];
                
[collectionView setContentOffset:attributes.frame.origin animated:YES];
```

where **collectionView** is your UICollectionView object, **index** is the row of the UICollectionView to which you want to scroll to and **section** is the section of the UICollectionView to which the row belongs to.

Answer (score 1):

```
_collectionView.pagingEnabled = NO;
[_collectionView scrollToItemAtIndexPath:indexPath atScrollPosition:(UICollectionViewScrollPositionLeft) animated:NO];
_collectionView.pagingEnabled = YES;
```

Comment: Can you please add some explanation?